# Ejecutar método de un fichero externo en un método de Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy intentando ejecutar un método de una librería externa dentro de otro metodo de Vue (no sé si debería hacerlo en una computed property), pero solamente consigo obtener el resultado del mismo si lo ejecuto así:

```
console.log(Metodo(number));
```

Entonces puedo ver en la consola el resultado correcto.

El método de Vue en el que intento ejecutarlo simplemente comprueba si el input no está vacío y después pretendo devolver el resultado de la entrada de dicho input.

```
methods: {
         isFormValid: function () {

             // console.log(Easter(this.last_year));   
             if(this.last_year != ""){
                    var when = Easter(this.last_year)
                    return when;
             }
         },
}
```

Posiblemente esté haciendo algo incorrecto dentro del método...

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
            :disabled="!isFormValid()">Continuar</button>
```

Gracias de antemano.

```
<div v-else>
        <h2>Bienvenido, {{ last_year }}</h2>
        {{ isFormValid() }}
</div>
```

++++

```
submitForm: function () {
       if (!this.isFormValid())
            return;
       this.formSubmitted = true;
}
```

Comment: donde usas el metodo este?

Comment: En un button que va dentro de un formulario.

Comment: probaste mostrar cuanto vale isFormValid directamente en tu form?? (asi {{isFormValid}}). y tambien, probaste :disabled="true" a ver si se muestra siempre prendido (o false para apagado?)

Comment: @gbianchi, he probado lo que comentaste de mostrar directamente {{isFormValid}} y sí, cuando envío el formulario muestra la salida correcta en dicha interpolación. Me muestra esto y la salida del método que es igual que lo introducido en el input, es decir, que es como si el método no hiciese nada.

Comment: Pero espera.. quien esta ejecutando ese metodo? porque ahi nadie lo esta ejecutando...

Comment: disabled no ejecuta un metodo. Alguien tiene que ejecutarlo, o ser una propiedad computada

Comment: gbianchi, en principio el método solo devolvía return this.last_year != "";, y cuando enviaba el formulario mostraba lo introducido en un campo de texto. GRacias por tu ayuda.

Comment: pero entendes el problema que tenes? las propiedades son reactivas, pero los metodos no. en este caso, tu metodo no se "activa" solo. Alguien lo deberia activar (e igual la propiedad disable no va a cambiar, salvo que le mandes una propiedad del componente que si sea reactiva), o tu metodo en realidad deberia ser una computed property.

Comment: @gbianchi, tengo otro método que envía el formulario. Mira la edición.

Comment: y submitForm funciona? ahora me mareaste con tu problema...

Comment: @gibianchi, sí, hasta que no introduzco algo en el input no se "activa" el button, y cuando envío el form hace me muestra lo introducido en el input y ahora provisionalemente la interpolación que me indicaste, Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Ok. entonces no entiendo si solucionaste el problema, o cual es el problema...